# Change a fixed-width text file to delimited

Tags: python

I have a file that has 27 fields and is fixed-width.  I would like to be able to run a script on it, that would go through and add a comma or something at the field end spots so that I can then easily import it into Excel without having to manually set the lengths each time.

I am able to read the file into Python, but am not sure how I would add the commas.

Field info:

Start Position: 1, 21, 41, 61, 81, 86, 89, 95, 99, 103, 183, 193, 243, 293, 343, 393, 423, 425, 435, 436, 437, 438, 440, 442, 445, 447, 450

Length: 20, 20, 20, 20, 5, 3, 6, 4, 4, 80, 10, 50, 50, 50, 50, 30, 2, 10, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you could use the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/io.html) library for this.

```
import pandas as pd

length = [20, 20, 20, 20, 5, 3, 6, 4, 4, 80, 10, 50, 50, 50, 50, 30, 2, 10, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1]

pd.read_fwf("input file.txt", widths=length).to_csv("output.csv")
```

You'll need to use either the `colspec` or `widths` keyword arguments in `pd.read_fwf` to specify how the column widths are laid out. More on that can be found [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html).

Answer (score 4):

You could do as follows,

```
from itertools import chain
import csv

n = 27 # num of fields
with open('in.csv') as fr, open('out.csv', 'w') as fw:
    reader = csv.reader(fr)
    writer = csv.writer(fw)
    for row in reader:
        row_ = chain(row, [None] * (n - len(row))
        writer.writerow(list(row_))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand what the itertools chain is doing here. I see that for each row there is a n-1 removing one of the 27 fields, but I'm still not able to define the field length or add a delimiter at the field length

Comment: @Tom I didn't get what you meant by 'add a delimiter at the field length'. `itertools.chain` puts the iterators back to back. there are `n` fields `len(row)` is there, you need to add `n-len(row)` more. where does `n-1` come from as you have commented?

Comment: @C Panda, I guess what I'm not understanding is how I define the lengths of the 27 fields with that for loop.

Comment: @Tom what do you mean by length of fields? you mean individual fields? say in `a,b,c` you want to configure width for like `a`?

Comment: @ C Panda, right, so field a may be 20 characters long, but field b might only be 3 characters.

Comment: @Tom why would you want to specify length? the interpreter will take care of that.

Comment: @C Panda when I run the file with this code, it converts the original file to csv, but puts all of the commas at the end of the text instead of in between fields so instead of being field a, field b, field c in the file.  It shows field a field b field c ,,

Comment: @Tom look closely. The commas that you see at the end : each comma with a comma before it signals an empty field. If you hvn't messed with the `delimiter` parameter(which u hvnt as you are getting commas) it will work. For example for `[1, 2, 3]` u will get `'1,2,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'`

Answer (score 2):

Use [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) to read in the fixed-format file and [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to generate the CSV file.